# python3.7 No module named pip

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7

i had a problem with installing packages to new upgraded python to version 3.7

When i type:

`python3.7 -m pip install pip -d`

> /usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip

I make easy_install like this: `sudo easy_install pip` what solve previous problems, but now it create pip3.7 in a weird way. Whem i calling for pip3.8 version, this returns me a message:

`pip3.7 -V`

> pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)

Someone know what i am doing wrong? I tried many things to resolve it. Reinstall, purge, install with symbolic link from python2 etc.

There is a script which i used to install python3.7 (i had also a problem with zlib):

```
sudo cd /home
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
sudo tar xf Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
sudo cd ./Python-3.7.3/
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3 10
python3 --version
```

Where is a mistake?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` (assuming *Ubuntu*).

Comment: why not just use the `pip3` binary?

Comment: `pip` is not part of `python`. You need to install it separately using the command provided by @CristiFati . Also I would suggest not to install `python` using the procedure that followed above. It caused some issues for me before. Here's a better way to do it. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04/ Try the 1st method in that.

Comment: @CristiFati seriously? I did it, previously I removed of course.

Comment: I don't know how *easy_install* works, but it seems that it automatically finds *Python 3.5*, which is wrong. You need to let it know that you want it for *3.7*. Also your env (*${PYTHONPATH}*) might cause some trouble.

Comment: I recompiled this with another way, and now it works :). Anyway, with `$path` and `apt` there isn't a solution. I checked it before i find solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Answer finally i find myself. There: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-debian-9/

There with similar errors you can recompile it, even without removal (on secound machine i checked without removal) failed installation before.

If someone want to good upgrade with everywith working on debian 9. I recommend that script:

```
NOW_DIR=$(pwd)
apt update
apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
mkdir ~/python_upgrade
cd ~/python_upgrade
curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.3
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j $(nproc)
make altinstall
python3.7 --version
cd $NOW_DIR
rm -rf ~/python_upgrade
```

There are minor changes from that commands in tutorial. Run above `file.sh` as root.

It can take some times, on my virtual machine with 2 cores during another job it takes 40 minutes. I hope someone find there good answer, not totally green comments like 'apt install' which is first try action before looking to web.